# JPA and Java 11

Tags: jpa, java-11, jakarta-ee

I'm currently developing a Java JPA desktop application. I want to use Java 11, however I cannot find tutorials to use JPA with Java 11.

So I need to ask, is JPA ready to Java 11, or should I go back to Java 8?

Is Eclipse Jakarta EE ready for use with Java 11?

Comment: The question is: where will you run the code? In an application server? If yes which one?

Comment: Desktop application, no servers

Comment: Hi Ossama, I current have a service running in production with Java 11, JPA and Spring Boot.

Comment: Any tutorial for JPA and Java 7/8 should work for you. There was no big differences in terms of the api.

Answer (score 0):

As Brother put it, there is no big difference.

JPA can be used both in JEE application servers and in JSE applications directly.
I have created applications using JPA based on Java 7, and they still run nicely on Java 11 and even 13.

Be aware outside of a container you have no CDI or CMT so you need to manage your EntityManager and transactions yourself.